# How to compile typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

If I use tsc it doesn't work. If I don't have tsc but have typescript, it still doesn't work. What can I do? [image: package json and error message]

Comment: You need the `tsc` command from the typescript library. Try uninstalling the npm package `tsc` and then installing the typescript package. Then `npx tsc` should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the typescript library like this.

`npm install typescript --save-dev`

Then `npx tsc` command will work.

What you have installed is a deprecated library called `tsc`
Check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc). So you may have to remove that first with the following command

`npm uninstall tsc`

Comment: That's what i did